# how do I get bundler to stop adding java to the end of the gem name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I am working on a project where I'm using a sinatra server inside a small application I'm writing.  We use JRuby 9.0.4.0 in the shop where I'm working.  The install works just fine when I do:

```
gem install mygem-1.0.0.gem
```

and it shows me

```
Successfully installed sinatra-1.4.7
Successfully installed mygem-1.0.0
```

When I add my gem to our existing project via gemfile

```
gem mygem, 1.0.0
```

And perform `bundle install`, I get:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "sinatra": 
  In Gemfile:
    mygem(= 1.0.0) java was resolved to 1.0.0, which depends on
      sinatra java
could not find gem 'sinatra java', which is required by gem 'mygem'............
```

Why can it work just fine when I do a gem install, but when I add the gem to my gemfile it cries about not being able to find a compatible gem.  Why is it looking for 'sinatra java' and how can I push it back to just 'sinatra'

NOTE: I have verified that the application works using the gem install method, but that is not the ideal method.

EDIT:

This is how the gem is specified in the gemspec

```
spec.add_runtime_dependency 'sinatra'
```

EDIT2:

The gemfile just has

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Specify your gem's dependencies in cucumber_distributed.gemspec
gemspec
```

Comment: @OlegSobchuk That doesn't explain at all why with bundler it's trying to find `sinatra java` instead of `sinatra` like it does during a `gem install`

Comment: Can you post your Gemfile?

Comment: @danielrsmith see edit2

Comment: I meant the rails projects gemfile

Answer (score 1):

Bundler adds the platform to the end of the gem name to indicate that it is running on a different platform than is specified in the gem's gemspec.

See issue: [Confusing error message when gemspec has a different platform than what's in Gemfile.lock](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/4259)

This can be solved by adding a platform specification in the gemfile, eg:

```
gem mygem, 1.0.0, platforms: :ruby
```